# Prove that the collection of sets where two finite measures agree in not necessarily a sigma-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I was given this tricky question where states as follow:

> Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $\nu$ be another measure on $(X,M)$. Moreover, assume that $µ(X) = ν(X) < ∞$. Prove, by constructing a suitable conunterexample that
> the family $\mathscr{A} = \{A ∈ M : \mu(A) = \nu(A)\} $ is not necessarily a σ-algebra.

One hint I was given: You can take $X = {a, b, c, d}$ and $µ$ the counting measure.

So far, instead of trying to find the counter-example, I think I proved that the collection has to be a sigma-algebra as follow:

If $A\in\mathscr{A}, \mu(A) = \nu(A)$, $\mu(A^c) =\mu(X)-\mu(A) = \nu(X)-\nu(A) = \nu(A^c)$, it means A is closed under complimet. Then, if $A,B \in \mathscr{A}, \mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B) = \nu(A)+\nu(B)-\nu(A\cap B) = \nu(A\cup B)$. Hence it is a algebra. Given the hint, the X is finite, so $\mathscr{A}$ is a sigma algebra.

Where did I miss? What can be a proper counter example?

Many Thanks!

Comment: How do you conclude that $\mu(A\cap B)=\nu(A\cap B)$ in the second part of your proof?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you are right. I should not assume that. But I still have no clue in constructing a counter example.

Comment: Possibly stupid question: what happens if you take $\nu$ to be the trivial measure? Then they only agree on the empty set which is not a sigma algebra...

Comment: @philbo_baggins well as stated in the question, $\mu(X)=\nu(X)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $$\begin{align}
\nu(\{a\})&=\frac12\\
\nu(\{b\})&=\frac32\\
\nu(\{c\})&=\frac32\\
\nu(\{d\})&=\frac12\\
\end{align}$$
and $\nu$ is extended to all of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ in the obvious manner.  Then $$\begin{align}
\nu(\{a,b\})&=2=\mu(\{a,b\})\\
\nu(\{a,c\})&=2=\mu(\{a,c\})\\
\nu(\{a,b\}\cap\{a,c\})&=\frac12\neq1=\mu(\{a,b\}\cap\{a,c\})
\end{align}$$